# Solving ODEs with Matlab, with varying Parameters

Tags: matlab, for-loop, ode

Lets say I have a simple logistic equation

*dx/dt = 2ax(1 - x/N)* 
where ***N*** is the carrying capacity, ***a*** is some growth rate, and both ***a*** and ***N*** are parameters I'd like to vary.

So what I want to do is to plot a 3D graph of my fixed point and the two parameters.

I understand how to find a fixed point of a single parameter.

Here is my sample code

```
function xprime = MyLogisticFunction(t,X) %% The ODE

% Parameters
N = 10 % Carrying Capacity
a = 0.5 % Growth Rate

x1prime = 2*a*X(1)*(1 - X(1)/N );

xprime = [x1prime ]';

end
```

Next my solver

```
% Initial Number 
x0 = 0.4;

%Time Window
tspan=[0 100];

[t,x]=ode45(@MyLogisticFunction,tspan,x0);

clf

x(end,1) % This gives me the fixed point for the parameters above.
```

So my real question is, how do I put a *for loop* across two functions, that allows me to vary ***a*** and ***N***, so that I can plot out a 3D graph of ***a*** and ***N*** and my fixed point x*.

I've tried combining both functions into one .m file but it does not seem to work

Comment: What are the **N** and **a** information throughout time?

Comment: I will vary it arbitrarily from say N = 10:1:20, a = 0.5:0.1:1.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the parameters to your function:

```
function xprime = MyLogisticFunction(t,X,a,N) %% The ODE

% Parameters (passed as function arguments)
% N = 10 % Carrying Capacity
% a = 0.5 % Growth Rate

x1prime = 2*a*X(1)*(1 - X(1)/N );

xprime = [x1prime ]';

end
```

and then when you call the `ode` solver:

```
% Initial Number 
x0 = 0.4;

%Time Window
tspan=[0 100];

a = 0.1:0.1:1; % or whatever
N = 1:10; % or whatever
x_end = zeros(length(a),length(N));

for ii = 1:length(a)
    for jj = 1:length(N)
        [t,x]=ode45(@(t,X)MyLogisticFunction(t,X,a(ii),N(jj)),tspan,x0);
        x_end(ii,jj) = x(end,1);
    end
end
```